# GLSL - Signed Distance Field vs normal Loop

Tags: glsl, signed-distance-field

I am fairly new in `GLSL` and only recently discover `Signed Distance Field`. I am trying to figure out how SDF can perform so well when you use [`mod()` function](http://glslsandbox.com/e#35086.0) to repeat but badly when you use [`for` loop function](http://glslsandbox.com/e#35131.1). 
I got a feeling that in `for` loop function, the ray marching is repeat as many times as the loop itself, but when using `mod()`, it only perform once. Can somebody explain in more detail how this works?

**UPDATE1:**

This is the `mod()` function:

```
float map( vec3 p )
{
    p.x=mod(p.x+3.0,6.0)-3.0;
    p.y=mod(p.y+3.0,6.0)-3.0;
    p.z=mod(p.z+3.0,6.0)-3.0;
    return box( p, vec3(1.,1.,1.) );
}
```

and Here is the `for()` loop function:

```
float map( vec3 p )
{
    p.yz = rotate(p.yz, mouse.y*10.);

    float b = box( p, vec3(1.,1.,1.) );
    float aa = b;

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    float off = float(i);
    vec3 q = p+off*.5;
    q.xz = rotate(q.xz, -mouse.x*off*12.);
    float c = box( q, vec3(off,1.,1.) );
    aa = fOpUnionRound(aa,c,.5);
    }
    return aa;
}
```

Comment: Can you post actual code samples? Without code it's very speculative. (But from what you did say, yes, doing something more-than-once will be slower than doing something once...)

Comment: Code Posted. Please check Update1.